# How to get broadcasted shape from input shapes?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I would like to get the shape of broadcast array from multiple input arrays. For example, I have several arrays of different but compatible shapes, I would like to know the shape of the sum of the input arrays from the shapes of the additives. Is there an easy way to obtain the following tuple?

```
(x+y+z).shape
```

Comment: can you detail your example by providing possible sizes for `x`, `y` and `z` ?

Comment: e.g., x.shape=(2,3,4), y.shape=(4,), z.shape=(), the resulting shape should be (2,3,4)